# How to update Python 3.4.0 to 3.4.10?

Tags: python-3.x

I am doing a project on Flask, on Windows Server 2003, you can install Python version not higher than 3.4.x on it, I installed Python 3.4.0 and (I can't / do not know) how to upgrade it to the final version 3.4.10?
How can I do it?

I downloaded from (https://www.python.org/downloads/release/python-3410/) Python-3.4.10.tgz and tried to install via (python setup.py install)

```
PS D:\DOWNLOAD\Python-3.4.10\Python-3.4.10> python setup.py install
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "setup.py", line 26, in <module>
    sysconfig.get_config_vars()['CFLAGS'] = cflags + ' ' + py_cflags_nodist
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'NoneType' and 'str'
```

Comment: Please read the `README` before trying random commands. This is not how this source package is supposed to be built. Instead you should follow the instructions in `PCbuild/readme.txt`

Answer (score 0):

download `Python-3.4.10.tgz`, and then in that same directory, run `tar -zxvf Python-3.4.10.tgz` to extract Python

2. `cd` into the directory where Python has been extracted to
3. `Run ./configure`
4. `Run make`
5. `Run make install`
6. `Run python --version`  ## to check that the installation was successful

This will help you install the python with a particular version.